# Форма не проходит валидацию. Django 2.1.2

Tags: python, django

Django 2.1.2
views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.views.generic import View
    from django.contrib import messages
    from guess.models import Post, Comments
    from guess.forms import PostForm, CommentsForm
    # Create your views here.
    class GuessBook(View):
        def get(self, request):
            get_date=Post.objects.all()
            context = {'post':get_date}
            return render_to_response('guessApp/form.html', context)
        def post(self,request):
            print(request.POST)
            form = PostForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                db = form.save()
            else:
                print('error')
            c = {'form':form}
            return render(request,'guessApp/form.html', c )
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    article = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    text=models.TextField(max_length=200)
    is_created=models.DateTimeField('Date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from guess.models import Post
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields=[
            'article',
            'text'
        ]
```

Вот, что выдает print(request.POST):

> QueryDict: 
>   {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['3H3Zqte3y11v645QOTUMqcak5ve7bxWyYsS6oUR2Y1hxvHixuqrTeAeHOmCXYeqw'], 
>   'Article': ['Some Article'], 'Text': ['TEXT TEXT']}>

Чтобы я не делал, форма не проходит валидацию.

Comment: Ну вы хоть почитайте-то, какие ошибки пишет не прошедшая валидацию форма

Comment: Единственное, что мне пишет эта форма - The Post could not be created because the data didn't validate.

Comment: В `form.errors` лежат нормальные тексты ошибок

Comment: Скорее всего ошибка возникает из-за поля даты(`is_created`), т.к. у него нет дефолтного значения или возможности установить null. Добавьте в модели Post к полю `is_created` параметр `auto_now_add=True`, при создании объекта будет записывать текущую дату автоматически.